# CSS Parse Error When Validating in w3c

Tags: html, css, parsing, w3c

When I try to validate my CSS code on w3c, it gives me these errors sorry if this has already been asked but I can't seem to find an answer. Some errors where fixed but these ones are still there.

```
Parse Error <html> <head> > <title>style2.CSS</title> </head> <body> html{ background-image: url(headerimg.jpg);    }
```

130     Parse Error

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type";content="text/html";charset="UTF-8"/>

    <title>style2.CSS</title>

</head>

<body>

html{
background-image: url(headerimg.jpg);   


}
header{

background-image: url(headerimg.jpg);
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:1000px 150px;


}

body{

background-image:url(bg.jpg);
padding-left:175px;
padding-right:175px;
width:940px;
}



#text{

background-color:white;
padding-top:0px;    
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:69.5px;
width:600px;
padding-bottom:0px;
display:inline-block;


}

#headchoix{

background-color:#333;
height:50px;

word-wrap: normal;
padding-top:30px;
}
 #bot{

float: top;
float:right;
background-color:#D3D3D3;
height:713px;
padding-left:0.1px;
width:250px;
}
#top1,#top2,#top3,#top4,#top5,#top6{
padding-right:40px;
color:white;    
padding-left:10px;
font-size:150%;
 font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration:none; 
}
#pad{

float:left;
}
#footerchoix{

background-color:#333;
width:940px;
height:160px;
display:inline-block;
}

#aside2,#aside1{
float:left;
padding-right:170px;
color:white;
}
#aside3{
float:left;
color:white;
}
#aside4{
float:right;
color:white;
width:200px;
}


a:visited{
color:black;
}
a:hover{

color:red;
}
a:active{

color:yellow;
}

a:link{
color:blue;
}


</body>
```

Comment: You say CSS, but you seem to validate HTML (with CSS code as content).

Answer (score 0):

Your meta tag has erroneous semi-colons:

This:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type";content="text/html";charset="UTF-8"/>
```

Should read:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
```

As the validator suggests, there was a parse-error at the semi-colon before the `content` attribute. That is because you are not supposed to separate attributes with semi-colons. You use white-space characters to separate  attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You should put CSS inside style tags

```
<style>
html{
background-image: url(headerimg.jpg);   


}
header{

background-image: url(headerimg.jpg);
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:1000px 150px;


}

body{

background-image:url(bg.jpg);
padding-left:175px;
padding-right:175px;
width:940px;
}



#text{

background-color:white;
padding-top:0px;    
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:69.5px;
width:600px;
padding-bottom:0px;
display:inline-block;


}

#headchoix{

background-color:#333;
height:50px;

word-wrap: normal;
padding-top:30px;
}
 #bot{

float: top;
float:right;
background-color:#D3D3D3;
height:713px;
padding-left:0.1px;
width:250px;
}
#top1,#top2,#top3,#top4,#top5,#top6{
padding-right:40px;
color:white;    
padding-left:10px;
font-size:150%;
 font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration:none; 
}
#pad{

float:left;
}
#footerchoix{

background-color:#333;
width:940px;
height:160px;
display:inline-block;
}

#aside2,#aside1{
float:left;
padding-right:170px;
color:white;
}
#aside3{
float:left;
color:white;
}
#aside4{
float:right;
color:white;
width:200px;
}


a:visited{
color:black;
}
a:hover{

color:red;
}
a:active{

color:yellow;
}

a:link{
color:blue;
}
</style>
```

Include this in head tag